# Bluetooth LE GattDeviceServicesResult TypeLoadException from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, typeloadexception

I'm building a WPF app in Visual Studio 2017, running Windows 10 version build 10586.164, and trying to connect to a bluetooth LE device.  I've added references to:

- System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll

from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.  I also added references to:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\5.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd

When I run this code:

```
    public async Task Connect()
    {
        _device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync("12:34:56:78:90:AB");

        var svcresult = await _device.GetGattServicesAsync();
        foreach (var service in svcresult.Services)
        {
            var chrresult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
            foreach(var chr in chrresult.Characteristics)
            {
                var dscresult = await chr.GetDescriptorsAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

It immediately fails, before even attempting to connect, with a type load exception for Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.GattDeviceServicesResult.  I can build and I can see the type in the object browser just fine.  Do I need the creators update to make any of this work, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Dan, did you every figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504538/correct-library-or-runtime-for-gattdeviceservicesresult-for-ble-in-net